# How do you overwrite the `click` event of a jQuery-selected element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my program I'm trying to modify the click event of a jQuery element and what I've noticed is that it actually ***adds*** a new event. So if I do

```
$myelem = $('.nav-item'); 
$myelem.click(function(){
    console.log("foo"); 
});
$myelem.click(function(){
    console.log("bar"); 
});
```

then clicking an element of class `nav-item` logs

> foo
>
> bar

How can I rewrite this so that the 2nd definition overwrites the previous click event?

Comment: You can use `off`  https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/wwr0mne4/

Answer (score 3):

If you can't modify first, then you can do it with [**off()**](http://api.jquery.com/off/), as it is more preferable way than **[.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)**:

```
$myelem = $('.nav-item'); 
$myelem.click(function(){
    console.log("foo"); 
});
$myelem.off('click').on('click',function(){
    console.log("bar"); 
});
```

As @CMedina suggested, you should also use  `$myelem.on("click",function(){....})`, since`.click()` is already in the background calling `.on('click',function..);`
Check the **below snippet**

```js
$myelem = $('.nav-item');
$myelem.click(function() {
  console.log("foo");
});
$myelem.off('click').on('click', function() {
  console.log("bar");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-item">Navigation</div>
```

Comment: unbind is old, off is the best option!, It would be good use `$myelem.on("click",function(){....})`